# Why are else statements discouraged in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, coding-style, conditional-statements

I was looking for a Ruby code quality tool the other day, and I came across the [pelusa](https://github.com/codegram/pelusa) gem, which looks interesting. One of the things it checks for is the number of else statements used in a given Ruby file.

My question is, why are these bad? I understand that `if/else` statements often add a great deal of complexity (and I get that the goal is to reduce code complexity) but how can a method that checks two cases be written without an `else`?

To recap, I have two questions:

1) Is there a reason other than reducing code complexity that else statements could be avoided?

2) Here's a sample method from the app I'm working on that uses an `else` statement. How would you write this without one? The only option I could think of would be a ternary statement, but there's enough logic in here that I think a ternary statement would actually be more complex and harder to read.

```
def deliver_email_verification_instructions
  if Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.development?
    deliver_email_verification_instructions!
  else
    delay.deliver_email_verification_instructions!
  end
end
```

If you wrote this with a ternary operator, it would be:

```
def deliver_email_verification_instructions
  (Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.development?) ? deliver_email_verification_instructions! : delay.deliver_email_verification_instructions!
end
```

Is that right? If so, isn't that way harder to read? Doesn't an `else` statement help break this up? Is there another, better, `else`-less way to write this that I'm not thinking of?

I guess I'm looking for stylistic considerations here.

Comment: That's pretty good, and some of what I was looking for (though a bit over my head at parts). Care to post that as an answer, elaborate, and for extra karma points, refactor my example or use one of your own to illustrate? Or do you feel like that post should work as an answer?

Comment: Overuse is bad, as is a rigid insistence that it be avoided. There's a time and a place, and, with properly written code, occasionally it's the right solution. It can be confusing with spaghetti code, so avoid writing poorly thought-out code and the rest should take care of itself.

Comment: do you really want to take advice from a lint tool that tells you, you are using "descriptive names" as long as the names are longer than two characters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me begin by saying that there isn't really anything *wrong* with your code, and generally you should be aware that whatever a code quality tool tells you *might* be complete nonsense, because it lacks the context to evaluate what you are actually doing.

But back to the code. If there was a class that had exactly one method where the snippet

```
if Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.development?
    # Do stuff
else
    # Do other stuff
end
```

occurred, that would be completely fine (there are *always* different approaches to a given thing, but you need not worry about that, even if programmers will hate you for not arguing with them about it :D).

Now comes the tricky part. People are lazy as hell, and thusly code snippets like the one above are easy targets for copy/paste coding (this is why people will argue that one should avoid them in the first place, because if you expand a class later you are more likely to just copy and paste stuff than to actually refactor it).

Let's look at your code snippet as an example. I'm basically proposing the same thing as @Mik_Die, however his example is equally prone to be copy/pasted as yours. Therefore, would should be done (IMO) is this:

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    @target = (Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.development?) ? self : delay
  end

  def deliver_email_verification_instructions
    @target.deliver_email_verification_instructions!
  end
end
```

This might not be applicable to your app as is, but I hope you get the idea, which is: Don't repeat yourself. Ever. Every time you repeat yourself, not only are you making your code less maintainable, but as a result also more prone to errors in the future, because one or even 99/100 occurrences of whatever you've copied and pasted might be changed, but the one remaining occurrence is what causes the `@disasterOfEpicProportions` in the end :)

---

Another point that I've forgotten was brought up by @RayToal (thanks :), which is that if/else constructs are often used in combination with boolean input parameters, resulting in constructs such as this one (actual code from a project I have to maintain):

```
class String
  def uc(only_first=false)
    if only_first
      capitalize
    else
      upcase
    end
  end
end
```

Let us ignore the obvious method naming and monkey patching issues here, and focus on the if/else construct, which is used to give the `uc` method two different behaviors depending on the parameter `only_first`. Such code is a violation of the Single Responsibility Principle, because your method is **doing more than one thing**, which is why you should've written two methods in the first place.

Comment: This is the best possible refactoring IMHO of the OP's code.  `if` statements with `else` parts are usually frowned upon because when you see them your enclosing methods is **doing more than one thing**, a violation of the SRP (although I would never argue for following this 100% of the time).  Your initialization of the target based on environment is not doing more than one thing; it is computing the correct target.  Then the delivery method is great. +1

Answer (score 2):

```
def deliver_email_verification_instructions
  subj = (Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.development?) ? self : delay
  subj.deliver_email_verification_instructions!
end
```

Comment: A solid refactoring of the method I wrote, which I appreciate. Any context you can add to address my first question, why you chose this style, and what this method objectively offers one with an `else` statement? That, I could mark correct.